# How do I use a method I have made? JAVA

Tags: java, methods

I have created this method to find the discrimiant using the function b^2-4ac

```
public class Discriminant {
public double Disc (double a, double b, double c){
        double disc;
        disc = Math.pow(b, 2) - 4*a*c;
        return disc ;
    }


}
```

Then i made  another method to find all positive roots of a function

```
public class PlusRoot {

    public double plusRoot (double a, double b, double c){
        double proot;
        proot = -b + Math.sqrt(disc)/ 2*a;
        return proot;
    }
}
```

But it is not working because it says disc cannot be resolved as a variable, both methods are in the same package... how do I fix this?

Comment: Hi, this look like C#, right? Do you have a `main` function somewhere?

Comment: @Stefan this is actually java sorry

Comment: Can you provide that part of the code that causes error? Actually usage of these methods.

Answer (score 0):

You have created a constructor and a method in two different classes, and you havent' declared them `static` - this means that to call them, you will need to create the appropriate instances first.

Instead, make the constructor a method, mark them both as `static` and move them into the same class, preferably in the same class as your `main()` method; then they'll be in the same namespace and you can just call them by their names.

Comment: I made them static and put them in my main method, I still get "disc cannot be resolved as a variable"

Comment: > preferably in the same class as your main() method;
and why? i guess it's better not to mix up all ur classes/methods with different functionality in one big main. Or have I misunderstood something?

Comment: @solar yes, but one must learn how to crawl before one can walk.

Answer (score 0):

"how do I fix this?" <- have you tried fixing it :) ?

Do you have a main method in your program ??

```
public static void main (String args[]) {
   // stuff here
}
```

If not then you need this to even run the program.

There are few ways you can fix this. But firstly i would suggest renaiming your method ... Java methods should start with a Lower Case !

First:

```
private Discriminent disc;

public double plusRoot (double a, double b, double c){
        disc = new Discriminent();

        double proot;
        proot = -b + Math.sqrt(disc.Disk(variables here))/ 2*a;
        return proot;
}
```

Second:

```
public static void main(STring args[]) {
  Discriminent disc = new Discriminent();
  double x = disc.Disck(values here);

  PlustRoot pr = new PlusRoot(disc);

}

and inside your PlusRoot you can have a constructor which takes disc as parameter 

public class PlusRoot {
  public double disc; 
  public PlusRoot(double disc) {
    this.disc = disc;
  }

  // and then you can call disc within that instance by doing 'this.disc';

  so: proot = -b + Math.sqrt(this.disc)/ 2*a;


}
```

and many more ways you can fix this :)

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the error is that you do not have the variable `disc`. You need to initialize it before using it. You would need a line like

```
double disc = 0.0;
```

However, I am also guessing your intention was to use the return value of your `Disc` method. With how your two classes are set up now. You would have to instantiate a Discriminant object and then call the method `Disc` method like so before you use the variable `disc`.

```
Discriminant discriminant = new Discriminant();
double disc = discriminant.Disc(a, b, c); //or whatever 3 doubles you wish to use.
```

Look into different scope variables in java to better understand this issue.