# Using methods I have created in a program - Java

Tags: java, point

Alright so I have created 2 methods called Point and LineSegment (they both work).

Point is this:

public class Point {

```
private double x;
private double y;
public Point(){
    x=0;
    y=0;
}
public Point(double a, double b){
    x=a;
    y=b;
}
public double getY(){
    return y;
}
public double getX(){
    return x;
}
public void setX(double newX){
    x= newX;
}
public void sety(double newY){
    y= newY;
}
public void setXY(double newX, double newY){
    x = newX;
    y = newY;
}
public String toString(){
    return "("+x+" , "+y+")";
}
```

}

LineSegment is this :

public class LineSegment {

```
private Point A;
private Point B;

public LineSegment (){
    A = new Point();
    B = new Point();
}
public LineSegment (int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2){
    A = new Point(x1, y1);
    B = new Point(x2, y2);
}
public LineSegment(Point P, Point Q){
    A = new Point(P.getX(), P.getY());
    B = new Point(Q.getX(), Q.getY());
}
public double Length(){
    double length = Math.sqrt(Math.pow( (B.getX() - A.getX()), 2) + Math.pow((B.getY() - A.getY()),2));
    return length;
}
public double Slope(){
    double slope = (B.getY() - A.getY() )/ (B.getX() - A.getX());
    return slope;
}
public String toString(){
    return "("+A.getX()+" , "+A.getY()+") + ("+B.getX()+" , "+B.getY()+") ";
}
```

}

As I said both of these codes work but now my task is to use Linesegment to create 2 line segments called AB and CD, and to output the slope of both of them, I am not sure how to do this, can anybody help?

Comment: You mean....you need to create Main class and utilize your code?  That should be easy.

Comment: Can you show me how it is done I am confused, i am not sure what i should be calling and such @Draco18s

Comment: Have you never created a Hello World program?

Comment: I have but that has nothing to do with something like this lol, if it is litterally so simple then show me because it is not @Draco18s

Comment: Yes it does have to do with this.  You take a hello world program, you remove the hello world portion and you add the LineSegment portion.

Comment: The wording of this question is oddly similar to [another question of yours](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33790992/how-do-i-use-a-method-i-have-made-java). I suggest you go through some coding tutorials about basic object oriented programming

Comment: @SethZiotic There's no need to get rude. Of all people, you especially shouldn't be insulting other people's intelligence, considering that even most novice of programmers can answer this question.

Answer (score 1):

They are called classes, not methods.

And you've already made class instances in your `LineSegment` class at

```
A = new Point();
B = new Point();
```

So now, in some other class,

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Point A = new Point();
    Point B = new Point();
    Point C = new Point();
    Point D = new Point();   

    LineSegment AB = new LineSegment(A, B); 
    LineSegment CD = new LineSegment(C, D); 

    // output the slope
    System.out.println(AB.Slope());
}
```

Also, note that your `Slope` method will return a divide-by-zero error if you run this code as-is.

Answer (score 0):

Create a class, regardless of its name, and put the main method.
The method called main is essentially your starting point, where your code will start running.

```
public static void main(String[]args){
     LineSegment segment1 = new LineSegment(1,2,3,4);
     LineSegment segment2 = new LineSegment(5,6,7,8);

     System.out.println("The first slope is: " + segment1.Slope());
     System.out.println("The second slope is: " + segment2.Slope());
}
```